# Capture image after CSS3 transforms

Tags: html, image-processing, canvas, css

Is it possible to render an image with CSS3 transforms applied to it onto a canvas?

We have an image that has the CSS3 perspective transform applied to it which needs to be sent to the server and the only way I can think of doing that is by grabbing the data from the canvas.

I want to avoid having to send the four control points to the server where we could do the image processing. Could it also be done with some SVG to Canvas method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you might be able to replicate certain transformations within the canvas by setting the appropriate transform on the context, as described here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#transformations